# Simulating added instructions in RISC-V without running application

Tags: riscv

I am implementing new custom instructions in the RISC-V ISA, but I have not yet added compiler support for them. I'm looking for a way to test these instructions in the Rocket chip infrastructure using its C++ emulator by feeding a small set of instructions without having to compile a C/C++ application and running it through the emulator. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the riscv-tools/riscv-tests/isa directory in rocket-chip, which provides a whole suite of assembly-written tests that test specific instructions on the rocket core.